# Data no longer accessible after upgrade from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7

Tags: mysql, upgrade, freebsd, case-sensitive

I upgraded my FreeBSD server from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7 using the `pkg install mysql57-server` command, and turned on support for the InnoDB engine. After getting the changed configuration issues sorted out so I could run `mysql_upgrade -u root -p` successfully, it reported that practically all of my existing tables don't exist - because they are stored on disk with *StudlyCaps* file names.

I have

```
lower_case_table_names = 0
```

in the current and active configuration file (**/usr/local/etc/mysql/my.cnf**), but when I run `show variables like 'lower_case_table_names';` in the `mysql` interpreter I get

```
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| lower_case_table_names | 1     |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also tried

```
root@localhost [none]> set lower_case_table_names=0;
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'lower_case_table_names' is a read only variable
```

At [the MySQL documentation for lower_case_table_names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) I found this comment:

> If you are using InnoDB tables, you should set this variable to 1 on all platforms to force names to be converted to lowercase.

It appears that someone decided that "you *should set* this variable to 1" means "this variable **must** be 1" and removed the capability of changing it.

Among other problems, this means that `phpMyAdmin` now displays table names in all lower case letters, rather than the more readable *StudlyCaps* they were built with.  I'm also concerned that this will break *all* of my Web sites where the PHP code is written with the as-designed *StudlyCaps* table names.

Is there a way to fix this short of reverting to MySQL 5.6?

Comment: You can switch to case insensitive tablenames by using a mysql dump. Your php code will usually not break, unless you actually use the tablenames twice. Nevertheless =0 should work. Make sure you have that option under `[mysqld]`. Check any other config files listed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) that might take precedence. Run `mysqld --verbose --help` to check which value will be used when starting the server (if you start mysql 5.7 with =0 and it doesn't work, it will just exit, not switch to =1, so it might be set to 1 somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a `/usr/local/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file that was installed by the 5.7 upgrade which was overriding the settings in `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` that I knew about and was editing.

Once I removed (renamed) the offending "default" file, I was able to set `lower_case_table_names=0` in `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` and have the change recognized when I restarted the server.

I *thought* I had run

```
find / -name "my*.cnf"
```

to find any active configuration files.  Either I didn't see the one in `/usr/local/etc/mysql` or (more likely) I didn't realize it would be overriding the values I had set in `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`:  My (invalid) assumption was that once a configuration file was found MySQL would stop looking for another one.